# Using constants in React

Tags: reactjs

Currently the **constant** is defined in the following file

> admin/constants/serviceConstants

```
const FEE_TYPES = {
  flat: "flat",
  perUnit: "per_unit",
};
```

I have the following components

index.js

List.js

Form.js

Row.js

I need the `FEE_TYPES` in all the files.

So i am importing this in **EACH OF THESE** the files as follows.

```
import { FEE_TYPES } from "admin/constants/serviceConstants";
```

Rather than importing the constant in ALL the files, Is this the right way or should i go for options such as

- passing them in the components as props? `<List feeTypes={FEE_TYPES} />`
- Defining the constant in the mobx form(I am using mobx form btw) as static variable and using them in the component?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's your code, do it however you want

Comment: I don't find anything wrong in importing it in multiple places

Comment: When your data doesn't change there is no point in passing it as props or mobx imo

Answer (score -3):

I think it depends on what would you like to do using FEE_TYPES. Normally, we define **Constants** at constants.js (or something) and import constants for creating clean code or debugging by managing some variables more simple way.

But, If you use the FEE_TYPES related to business logic or reused at some code, it could be included in **Context API** or **Custom hooks**.

Current example, It seems not bad to import the FEE_TYPES at the all of the components to me.